# How do I call a function defined in a C++ DLL that has a parameter of type int *, from inside C# code?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a native regular C++ Dll which I want to call from C# code, so i created C++/CLI class (as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marshalCPPclass.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx)) which will include managed C++ code and which can be called by any C# code directly and which can make calls inturn to native unmanaged C++.

One of function in native C++ dll has parameter of type int *. How do I declare in wrapper function and how can i convert it into int *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("some.dll")]
static extern void SomeCPlusPlusFunction(IntPtr arg);
```

IntPtr is a type that is roughly equivalent to void *.

From your comment, you'd be best off doing something like this (C#):

```
int size = 3;
fixed (int *p = &size) {
    IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr(p));
    // do some work with data
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(data); // have to free it
}
```

but since AllocHGlobal can take an int, I don't know why you wouldn't do this:

```
IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
```

Comment: And then use the `ToPointer()` method to get the `void *` pointer, which you can then cast to `int *` and dereference.

Comment: Hi Folks, Thanks for reply, Im using following code segment to carry the pointer conversion based on your replies. Please tell me if im wrong. Apolozose for any silly mistake, im newbie in programming for C# & C++/CLI. int b=3; IntPtr errno = new IntPtr(&b); int *var = (int*)Marshal::AllocHGlobal(errno).ToPointer();

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks a lot for your replies, I got it working finally. I am using IntPtr to declare int and then use ToPointer to convert it and use it in native C++. But now i don't know how can I revert ir, i mean how to convert int* back to IntPtr. I request to reply, if anyone knows answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is the C/C++ way of passing a value by reference.  You should use the *ref* or *out* keyword:

```
[DllImport("something.dll")]
private static extern void Foo(ref int arg);
```

In C++/CLI that would look roughly like this:

```
public ref class Wrapper {
private:
    Unmanaged* impl;
public:
    void Foo(int% arg) { impl->Foo(&arg); }
    // etc..
};
```

Comment: Depending on the other parameters (if there's a size parameter near it) this could also be a way of passing dynamically allocated arrays.